# Java: Parsing Json with Gson for unknown field

Tags: java, json, gson

I making an parser for json with gson and it based on object model method. My problem is that I have an object on the json where there are some other JsonObjects in it but I don't know there names so I can't use the SerializedName. Also the number of the JsonObjects on the initial object is random. How to iterate the objects from the initial object?

**Json style:**

```
"initial_obj": {
     "random_name1": { }
     "random_name50": { }
     "random_name9": { }
}
```

Comment: on the org.json.JSONObject I can use an iterator to get all the names. I want something like that and on gson.

Comment: It's not a valid JSON string. Look for valid JSON sting in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the name of fields are not known in advance then convert it into `Map<String, Object>` using [`TypeToken`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html)

```
String str = "{\"initial_obj\": {\"random_name1\": { },\"random_name50\": { },\"random_name9\": { }}}";
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, Object> data = new Gson().fromJson(str, type);
System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(data));
```

output:

```
{
  "initial_obj": {
    "random_name1": {},
    "random_name50": {},
    "random_name9": {}
  }
}
```